# centre a website with masterpage?

Tags: asp.net

I want to use a div to centre a website, should this be done on the site.master or on each page?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="wrapper">
  //Rest Of Masterpage
</div>
```

in CSS

```
#wrapper
{
    margin: auto;
}
```

This should center everythign in your masterpage

Comment: Think if actually asked this incorrectly - some content pages are left-aligned and I'll keep tham that way, but when viewed in the browser the whole site is sitting to the left of the screen so Im looking to have the site centred in teh browser rather than the content, if that makes sense...   thanks

Comment: Thats what this should do for you.  you should put this div inside the body on your master page and everythign else inside of it.  It will center everything in the browser window.  From there you can apply CSS to specific areas to set the text align or what not.   Typically I would wrap the contextplaceholder in a div like <div id=content">

Comment: If you want to see an example of this working right on this page on stackoverflow if useing IE open the dev tools and drill down to the div id=content.  Its assigning margin: auto to left and right which causes the browser to center the entire div.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to your stylesheet

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
body { text-align:center; }
#container { width:960px; margin:0 auto; text-align:left; }
```

Then in the master page

```
<div id="container">

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
<center>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Content1" runat="server"/>
</center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**ASPX:**

```
<div id="main">
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#main { margin: 0 auto; }
```